# F2 rename variable doesn't work in vscode + jupyter notebook + python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I can use the normal F2 rename variable functionality in regular python files in vscode. But not when editing python in a jupyter notebook.

When I press F2 on a variable in a jupyter notebook in vscode I get the familiar change variable window but when I press enter the variable is not changed and I get this error message:

> No result. No result.

Is there a way to get the F2 change variable functionality to work in jupyter notebooks?

Here's my system info:

jupyter module version

```
(adventofcode) C:\git\leetcode>pip show jupyter
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\johan\anaconda3\envs\adventofcode\lib\site-packages
Requires: ipykernel, qtconsole, nbconvert, jupyter-console, notebook, ipywidgets
Required-by:
```

Python version:

```
(adventofcode) C:\git\leetcode>python --version
Python 3.10.0
```

vscode version:

```
1.63.2 (user setup)
```

vscode Jupyter extension version (from the changelog in the extensions window):

```
2021.11.100 (November Release on 8 December 2021)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that you put up a bug report in GitHub and see this issue: [Renaming variables didn't work](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7433), the programmer replied:

> Some language features are currently not supported in notebooks, but
> we are making plans now to hopefully bring more of those online soon.

So please wait for this feature.

Comment: Yes, I created the question here first but realized that the best place would be on the vscode-jupyter github page. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to rename variables in one cell by:

1. Select the variable
2. Right click and choose "Change All Occurrences"
3. Change the variable name

Comment: This only works in a single cell

Comment: That's helpful. BUT be aware that it includes commented out code.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + F2 ~ Change All Occurrences